# Поиск похожих гифок

Tags: php

Допустим, есть папка на сайте с гифками
Есть ли готовые библиотеки для поиска похожих гифок?

т.е. пользователь загружает гифку и сайт ищет, была ли она уже добавлена

Comment: Яндекс не так давно (вроде в прошлом году на хабре) публиковал алгоритм поиска похожих картинок. Если и не найдете библиотеку, можете сами попробовать ее написать, сложного вроде ничего нет.

Comment: Нашел на хабре от яндекса: [технология поиска похожих изображений](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/106520/), [поиск серий изображений](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/198830/), [Поиск по подобию. Поиск нечетких дубликатов. Лекции от Яндекса](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/256291/) (там же ссылка на другие лекции по изображениям)

Comment: @BOPOH, оформите, пожалуйста, написанное вами в виде ответа. если по каким-то причинам вы не хотите получать баллы репутации за этот ответ, его можно назначить «общим» (*checkbox* внизу справа).

Comment: Пока я не взялся все это копать, хочу спросить: для гифок это точно подойдет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько способов:

- Сравнение хэшей двух gif-ок;
- Использование ImageMagick: `Imagick::compareImages`;
- Использование специализированной библиотеки [Libpuzzle](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle).
- Сравнение файлов через [перцептивный хеш](http://www.phash.org/).

На Хабре есть  [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/company/io/blog/259549/) с детальным описанием.

Comment: Мне нужно искать дубликаты гифок, этот способ сойдет для гифок?